# Splitting a Column Value by a Condition and Taking the First Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I am attempting to group together multiple restaurant locations to represent one chain.

I have this column in my Data Frame:

```
Index|STORE_NAME
0    |Subway 17663-0
1    |Subway 1837-0
2    |Subway 1838-0
3    |Subway 1841-0
```

I want it to be able to group these stores, so I am attempting to split them and just take the "Subway" value so it will look like this:

```
Index|STORE_NAME
0    |Subway
1    |Subway
2    |Subway
3    |Subway
```

So far I have this code:

```
data['STORE_NAME'] = data['STORE_NAME'].str.split('Subway', 0, expand = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

If you have more transformation to apply, use `replace` with a mapping dict of regex:

```
rmap = {r'^Subway\s*.*': 'Subway', # starts with Subway followed by anything
        r'^Other\d+': 'Other}  # something like Other123, Other36
df['STORE_NAME'] = df['STORE_NAME'].replace(rmap, regex=True)
```

If you have only one transformation to apply, use indexing:

```
df.loc[df['STORE_NAME'].str.startswith('Subway'), 'STORE_NAME'] = 'Subway'
```

---

`str.split` need a separator (whitespace here) to split strings then use `str[0]` to keep only the first element:

```
>>> data['STORE_NAME'].str.split(' ').str[0]
0    Subway
1    Subway
2    Subway
3    Subway
Name: STORE_NAME, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have been more specific. I cannot split by the space because the data frame has other restaurants included where I do not want to split by the space in between. I need a unique way to split just the ones containing Subway.

Comment: @DomMunson. I get it. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're alright with using lambdas, here's a way to do it

```
data['STORE_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0] if x.startswith("Subway") else x)
```

This will only split by space for rows that have "Subway" in it and return everything else